# iPhone, edit image on top of another and save

Tags: ios, objective-c

Could someone outline how to do step 2 below in Objective-C for iOS?

The crucial part is "image loads onto "create" scene, in front of background image, with editing tools".

1. Choose background image from camera or library and place in "Create" scene.
2. From "Create" scene pick an image from a modal list, image loads onto "Create" scene, in front of background image, with editing tools for "flip", "Copy", "Behind", "Done". Image will touch/pinch to move, size and rotate. Editing tools hide when touch "Done". Touch image to toggle editing tools.
3. Save created image to library.

Comment: I feel comfortable with steps 1 and 3. Not sure where to begin with step 2; "image loads onto "create" scene, in front of background image, with editing tools".

Comment: @user1889138 - Welcome to StackOverflow!  You'll get the best answers from questions that include the code you've written so far, the results you're getting, and a detailed description of the results you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would load the background image into an image view and then have additional editable sub-views in front of it. Once you are done you renderLayerInContext of the entire view hierachy into a new image and save that.